# I want to change the index order for each row in the gridview

Tags: flutter

I want to create a `Gridview` in the following order. Changing the order of the indexes was possible, but changing the order of the tiles in the last row was not possible.
I couldn't find a way to place the tiles to the right when the last row is in reverse order.

**Last row in reverse order**

[image]

**When the last row is not in reverse order**

[image]

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: List.generate(10, (index) {
    
    bool isEvenRow = (index ~/ 3) % 2 == 0;
    int newIndex = isEvenRow ? index : (index ~/ 3 + 1) * 3 - 1 - index % 3;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Tile ${newIndex + 1}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

I tried to implement it using `StaggeredGrid`, but it was difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
final count = 10;
final extra = (3 - (count % 3)) % 3;
...
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: List.generate(count + extra, (index) {
    bool isEvenRow = (index ~/ 3) % 2 == 0;
    int newIndex = isEvenRow ? index : (index ~/ 3 + 1) * 3 - 1 - index % 3;
    if (newIndex >= count) {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Tile ${newIndex + 1}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```